# Sync between Azure and local Active Directory / Delete User

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365

we installed azure ad connect on our on-premise ad. its synced now our whole ad into the azureAD.
Because we just starting the project we only have 5 people which got licence for office 365 and we want now only these 5 user in the Azure AD.

In Azure admin panel I cannot delete the user, because it says u can only delete on on-premise ad. 
On the Azure ad connect client on the on-premise server I now configured it that it only sync the OU with the 5 User we want. But the other user are still in Azure AD.

I hope this is understandable, first stackoverflow article.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to delete the synced users in Azure Active Directory.

If you do not want to see those unwanted users in Azure Active Directory, you can stop synchronizing those users in Azure AD connect Server by filtering the objects.

If you want to remove the users completely then you need to go to your On-Premises Active Directory and you can delete those unwanted users except this 5 users.

See the [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2619062/you-can-t-manage-or-remove-objects-that-were-synchronized-through-the) for reference

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I dont want to delete them because the users are active working in our onpremise AD.
We just dont want them the see on our Admin panl in 365 in Users. 
i tried to configure the azure sync to only take the 5 users from the onpremise but it doesent work the other 500 users are still shown in Admin panel 365